# How to inconspicuously interview elsewhere

Tags: interviewing, work-environment, resignation

I have decided to leave my current company, but I am struggling with how to inconspicuously interview.  I've done a very poor job of scheduling interviews in a way so that they don't clearly signal red flags of my impending departure. By this I mean I've abruptly taken days off during the week to go do onsites and regularly slip out for an hour or so to do phone screens.  I don't want to be flaunting my desire to leave but at the same time I absolutely want be interviewing elsewhere as much as possible.

Comment: Do you actually have any interviews lined up? If so, just go to them.

Comment: Clearly a duplicate....

Answer (score 0):

Over lunch and after normal work hours tends to be best.  Most places understand how this works and will accommodate.